# All functions are called properly, still desired output is not obtained. Output is some random garbage value. Please explain the following code

Tags: c++

Why the following code produces garbage value instead of product of two numbers? While debugging many times destructor is being called. Somebody please explain me what is happening behind the scene. There are two classes A and B. A is inherited by the base class B and the operator "%" is overloaded to produce the product of two numbers of two different classes but the desired output is not obtained when called from the main().

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B;
class A
{
public:
    int x;
    A()
    {
    }

    ~A()
    {
    }
    friend int operator/(A, B);
    void acceptValue();
private:

};

class B :public A
{
public:
    int y;
    B()
    {
    }
    void acceptValueY()
    {
        cout << "Enter the value of y: ";
        cin >> y;
        return;
    }
    ~B()
    {
    }
    friend int operator/(A, B);
private:

};

int operator/(A obj1, B obj2)
{
    return obj1.x * obj2.y;
}

void A::acceptValue()
{
    cout << "Enter the value of x: ";
    cin >> x;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    A ob;
    B baseObj;
    ob.acceptValue();
    baseObj.acceptValueY();
    cout<<baseObj / (ob, baseObj);
}
```

Comment: It's this bit: `baseObj / (ob, baseObj)`. In particular that's not how operators accept two arguments, and you're using baseObj.x which isn't initialised.

Comment: "While debugging many times destructor is being called" - your operator should probably have const reference arguments, not just plain A and B.

Comment: See [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) and *initialize your variables*.

Comment: Off topic: it seems counter-intuitive to me to have `operator/` perform a multiplication.

Comment: The question states that "_the operator "%" is overloaded_" which makes it even more confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check inline comments for answer

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B;
class A
{
public:
    int x;
    A()
    {
    }
    /*A(const A& a)
    {

    }*/

    ~A()
    {
    }
    friend int operator/(A, B);
    void acceptValue();
private:

};

class B :public A
{
public:
    int y;
    B() // Will invoke A constructor. But value of member x in A object will be garbage as it is uninitialized.
    {
    }

    void acceptValueY()
    {
        cout << "Enter the value of y: ";
        cin >> y;
        return;
    }
    ~B() // Will invoke A destructor
    {
    }
    friend int operator/(A, B);
private:

};

int operator/(A obj1, B obj2)
{
    return obj1.x * obj2.y;
} // Destructor of A and B (and hence A again) will get called.

int test(A obj1, B obj2)
{
    return obj1.x * obj2.y;
}

void A::acceptValue()
{
    cout << "Enter the value of x: ";
    cin >> x;
    return;
}

int main()
{

    A ob;
    B baseObj;
    ob.acceptValue();
    baseObj.acceptValueY();
    // This way of invocation is causing garbage value. Firts arument is of type A. 
    // So copy construction of A type object will happen from baseObj.
    // But as B constructor causes default constrcution of A, value of member x is garbage.

    //int val = baseObj / (ob, baseObj);

    // Correct way of invocation
    int val = ob / baseObj; // It will show compute right val value.  Will invoke copy constructor of A and B as they are being passed by value.
    cout << val;
} // Destructor of A and B (hence again A) will get called.
```

Answer (score 2):

First, the comma-operator will evaluate the expression `(ob, baseObj)` and discard all but the last statement, so it evaluates to `baseObj`.

You end up with `cout << baseObj / baseObj` and the operator `int operator/(A obj1, B obj2)` effectively calculates `baseObj.x * baseObj.y`.

The randome values appear, because `baseObj.x` was never initialized and thus contains garbage.